# Java hash string for 600M sentences

Tags: java, hash

I wanted to check the exact duplicates for 600M Arabic sentences (each is less than 150 chars). So, I indexed texts and their hashs using Lucene.
I did hashed the texts as follows:

```
MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digester.update(sentence.getBytes());
int hashValue = new String(digester.digest()).hashCode();
```

My index has the following fields:

```
text: <sentence>
hash: <hashValue>
```

My idea is that, I have a list of sentences, and I want to get their exact duplicates, so I can search lucene using their hashes.

```
ScoreDoc[] results;
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(1000);
Query rangeQuery = LegacyNumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("hash", hashValue, hashValue, true, true);
searcher.search(rangeQuery, collector);
results = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

The problem is that, when I do so, I get different sentences with the same hash! So, I failed to achieve what I want!

So I want to get answers for the following questions:

- Would I get less collisions if I hashed words rather than sentences using this hash function?
- Is there a better hash function with less collections?
- Is there a better way to do my task?
- Is the hash language dependent even if the hash function uses bytes, so is their a better hash for utf-8 texts?

I appreciate your responses!
Regards,
Reem

Comment: *"I get different sentences with the same hash"* Well, yeah!! Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique. They *cannot* be unique.

Comment: A hash is an int, so its values are finite

Comment: A hash collision by itself isn't necessarily bad, provided that it is handled correctly.  How are you resolving collisions currently?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I'm not handling the collision, that's why I'm posting this question to solve this issue.

Comment: @Andreas So, is there a good way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat how the fact that int values are finite would help to avoid collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index them with Lucene, you don't really need the hashes. Just store the sentences as (untokenized) `StringField` and use a `TermQuery` with the exact sentence.

Comment: I'm storing hashes because I'm doing some processing to the Strings before comparing them (e.g., removing URLs) because I want to compare texts without URLs, but eventually I need the original texts for other purposes.

Comment: Then I would index and search the processed text (instead of the hash). You can store the original sentence in a `StoredField`. No need to index that as well.

Comment: See https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html

Comment: It's more about space optimization!